# Building the apk using the ant script .

Tags: android, ant, build, apk

I am facing problem in creating the .apk file using the ant script . The generated .apk named as _unaligned.apk instead of .apk and on installing the _unaligned.apk file to the device I get force-close showing the java.lang.VerifyError exception, but the same apk generated using IDE works fine. I am struck on this for a long time. Can you share the build.xml file that generates the .apk file?

Answer (score 3):

[this Bloq entry](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html) explains all necessary steps. Especially if you want to customize your build script.

If your are looking for the actual build script, just look into your Android SDK folder platforms/android-X/templates. There should be a file called android_rules.xml.

I customized my build script to clean, build, sign and distributing the apk to an attached device. If you like, I can provide you with my script. Just contact me!

Comment: Could u help me in cutomising ant build script. I am trying to bind few folders to the apk before it is generated..check my [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835940/android-is-it-possible-to-add-folders-to-apk-through-commands#comment19042950_13835940)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use zipalign & sign your apk with some key; as long as you're testing the app you can simply use the debug key with `ant debug`

At least that's what I understand from [this page](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/developing/other-ide.html) which you may want to read carefully.

Comment: Seems to be the only correct response to the question. It clearly seems the alignment step failed or was not called by ANT.

Answer (score 0):

What ant command are you running at the command / terminal prompt?

I have been having different problems with manually running ant ([Repackage apk file to contain custom assets what build tool to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793220/repackage-apk-file-to-contain-custom-assets-what-build-tool-to-use)) and there might be some info on that thread to help you.

Alternatively, remember that one needs to sign the apk file before deploying it (see Joubarc's link).