# Android: Is it possible to add folders to APK through commands

Tags: android, ant

I am having a android source and i am building that source and generate apk manually. Manually in the sense using ant release jarsigner and zipalign. I got the singed APK working. Now i am trying to add folders to the apk before signing it or It is possible to add it while the ant build process .Is this possible if so share me the commands.I saw aapt command is used to add files but not folders..

Thanks in Advance

Regards,

Deepak

Comment: i think it is not possible for signed apk or may be also not for unsigned apk

Comment: Actually if we can add files means it ll be posible to add folders right? And also is there any possible to add in the build.xml or somewhere to bind folders to the apk?

Comment: "Now i am trying to add folders to the apk before signing it" -- that does not make any sense.

Comment: @CommonsWare My actual requirement is , If u see a titanium based app's APK it has folders like org and ti but these folders are not present in the Pure Android apk.. How this difference is occuring.. Both uses ANT tool to build a apk but stil the folders sturcture is differing..I need my apk should contain org and ti folders so only..I think u can understand now..